# Capsule collider triggered unexpectedly

Tags: unity, collider

I have an object with a capsule collider on its root, with `IsTrigger=true` (triggered by the player). The trigger works fine, but is also triggered unexpectedly some times when the player walks near the collider, but still way out of its range.

See attached image: the capsule collider limits are wel within the round circle object. On the right you see that the player has triggered the trigger, while it was far away from the collider.

When I run circles around the collider, this will happen sometimes. Location appears to be random and it doesnt happen if the player is further away than say 10 meters.

Anyone else have this issue or can tell me what is causing it?

[image]

Comment: Are there any other colliders attached to your teleporter? Try disabling the capsule collider component in the inspector and see if you are still able to trigger your teleporter.

Comment: Checked the colliders at runtime (didn't think about doing that..) and discovered that an additional collider was added to my player that I didn't know about! Thanks!